# Using VBA to search web site and return information

Tags: excel, vba

I have not used excel VBA very much but I am trying to enter a part number into a cell and have it return the interchange information. I did some looking around and was able to come up with a way to return the info on a separate excel sheet where i can then copy and paste. However i was wondering if there  was a way that i could have it move down column A gathering the info for each part number and putting it into the rows for each interchange.

This is what i have currently:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row = Range("ZF_number").Row And _
Target.Column = Range("ZF_number").Column Then
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    'IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.liftsupportsdepot.com/search/search-results/?search_query=" & Range("ZF_number").Value
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = IE.document
    Dim sDD As String
    sDD = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("span")(32).innerText)
    IE.Quit
    Dim aDD As Variant
    aDD = Split(sDD, ",")
    Range("Interchange_1").Value = aDD(0)
    Range("Interchange_2").Value = aDD(1)
    Range("Interchange_3").Value = aDD(2)
    Range("Interchange_4").Value = aDD(3)
    Range("Interchange_5").Value = aDD(4)
    Range("Interchange_6").Value = aDD(5)
    Range("Interchange_7").Value = aDD(6)
    Range("Interchange_8").Value = aDD(7)
    Range("Interchange_9").Value = aDD(8)
    Range("Interchange_10").Value = aDD(9)
    Range("Interchange_11").Value = aDD(10)
    Range("Interchange_12").Value = aDD(11)
    Range("Interchange_13").Value = aDD(12)
    Range("Interchange_14").Value = aDD(13)
    Range("Interchange_15").Value = aDD(14)
    Range("Interchange_16").Value = aDD(15)
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You mean looping over column A cell contents? Like using `Do ... Loop` statement? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement

Comment: Currently on the script that i have i would need to enter the part number and hit enter to start the process. Would doing a loop statement move down column A work with the values already in the cells? Sorry if I am not understanding too much I'm trying to learn as i go.